# Using CustomTypeConverter when the Type is an Array of CustomType

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I have a Class called ListRevision which has a name and a Revision number.

I made a TypeConverter for it.

The problem is that when I go to use it, the actual type is ListRevision[] (Because its an array).  When trying to convert the Array, it fails because there is no ListRevision[] TypeConverter.  How do I get it to use my TypeConverter for each object in the array?

```
[System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter(typeof(ListRevisionConverter))]
public partial class ListRevision
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.hotlistName; }
        set { this.hotlistName = value; } 
    }

    public string Revision
    {
        get {  return this.revision;  }
        set {  this.revision = value; }
    }
}
```

I call it with

```
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ListRevision[])); 
return tc.ConvertFromString( s); // s is the string I am converting from.
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want an array of `ListRevision` from one string value ? Not from an array of string ?

Comment: Can you also show an example of the input string and the code of the ListRevisionConverter too?